# How can I create a table to hold data from an iteration in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, iteration, matlab-table

Let us suppose that we have two matrices as input, `X` and `Y`. I would like to regress each column of `Y` on each column of `X` and calculate several parameters, then create a table for the results. Here is my starting code:

```
function [Table]=create_table(Y,X)
    [n,p]=size(X); % size of both matrix is X
    for ii=1:p % iterate  over all variable 
        x=X(:,i);
        y=Y(:,ii);
        x = [ones(size(x)) x];% construct  X matrix 
        [b,~,~,~,~] = regress(y,x);

        %% let us suppose we would like to calculate two parameters
        unknown=b(1)*100-b(2);
        known=b(2)/b(1)+200
    end
end
```

What I want to get as a result is following table (let us suppose that `p = 3`):

[image]

I know there is a `table` command in MATLAB, but I don't know how to use it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately before your for loop, you can initialize your [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) (filled with zeroes to start) like so:

```
T = table((1:p).', zeros(p, 1), zeros(p, 1), ...
          'VariableNames', {'Iteration', 'Unknown', 'Known'});
```

Then you can [fill in rows of your table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) within your loop by replacing the calculations of `unknown` and `known` with this:

```
T.Unknown(ii) = b(1)*100-b(2);
T.Known(ii) = b(2)/b(1)+200;
```

Comment: after cycle should i  fill table?

Comment: @datodatuashvili: I don't know what you mean. I think I made it clear where the lines above have to go in your code?

Comment: i will try and  i will post  if something i didnot undertsnad

Comment: what does this code means?Error using optimal_estimation (line 44)
To assign to or create a variable in a table, the number of rows must match the height of the table

Comment: @datodatuashvili: Make sure that when you are accessing a variable in the table you are typing the name *exactly* as it appears in the table (case matters).